# JavaFX8 DatePicker Button size change

Tags: java, css, javafx, datepicker

I am using JavaFX `DatePicker` which has default style.

However, I want to apply CSS styling to all buttons in this `Scene` by adding `scene.getStyleSheets().add("abc.css")`.

It worked fine and I applied:

```css
Button {
    -fx-font-size: 20;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
    -fx-pref-width: 300;
    -fx-pref-height: 60;
    -fx-background-radius: 16px;
    -fx-background-color: lightgrey;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

However the problem happens when I added `DatePicker`. The `DatePicker` has its own arrow buttons inside which is to switch month or year. I want to use default style for this `DatePicker` but since it is under my `Scene`, its buttons get the button styling from the CSS... (fat buttons)

Is there a way for me to remove the button style from the `DatePicker` to use default `DatePicker` styling? I do not want to remove all styling from this scene since I have to apply all the rest by my own.

Here's a photo:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to prevent a style from being applied to nodes with a certain ancestor. This requires you to

- come up with a way to restrict the nodes your style is applied in a way that does not modify the decendants of e.g. `DatePicker`, or
- reset the properties you modified to the values `modena.css` applies to them.

For the second option you could use

```css
Button {
    -fx-font-size: 20;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
    -fx-pref-width: 300;
    -fx-pref-height: 60;
    -fx-background-radius: 16px;
    -fx-background-color: lightgrey;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.date-picker-popup > * > .spinner > .button {
    -fx-font-size: 1em;
    -fx-font-family: "System";
    -fx-pref-width: -1;
    -fx-pref-height: -1;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.date-picker-popup > * > .spinner > .button:focused {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color, -fx-inner-border, -fx-body-color, -fx-faint-focus-color, -fx-body-color;
}
```

However note that this needs to be done to every standard control that uses a button. Adding a way to select the buttons you want to style maybe much simpler. You could e.g. add a styleclass to the buttons you want to style:

```
button.getStyleClass().add("my-style");
```

```css
Button.my-style {
    -fx-font-size: 20;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
    -fx-pref-width: 300;
    -fx-pref-height: 60;
    -fx-background-radius: 16px;
    -fx-background-color: lightgrey;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a absolutely correct solution, but as a workaround you could inherit your javaFX styles for date-picker popup control

If you add this to your abc.css, buttons would as normal as default

```
.date-picker-popup > * > .spinner > .button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-pref-width: -1;
    -fx-pref-height: -1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted!